# issue while sending mail using php mailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have send an email using php mailer class. mail was sending successfully but I got the mail content as 'logo 1'. am using the following code.. anybody please help

```
<?
include_once 'editors/tinymce.php';
$to = 'test@test.com';
$frm = 'test1@test1.com';
$sub = 'Weekly Working Report';

$mail_body = include_once('mail_content.php');
$mailstatus = l_mail('', '', $to, '', $frm, '', $sub, $mail_body);

if ($mailstatus == 'ok') {
    echo '<center><font color=red style="font-size:14px">Message has been sent Succesfully.....!</font></center><br>';
} else {
    echo $mailstatus;
}
?>
```

Comment: what's the content of main_content.php?

Comment: I "+1" this comment : if your mail is correctly sent, your problem is about content. It can also be a HTML problem, if you forgot to add html headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you shouldn't write as `$mail_body = include_once('mail_content.php');` 
instead,

```
include_once 'editors/tinymce.php';
$to = 'test@test.com';
$frm = 'test1@test1.com';
$sub = 'Weekly Working Report';

    ob_start(); // start output buffering
    include_once('mail_content.php');
    $mail_body = ob_get_contents(); // get the contents from the buffer
    ob_end_clean();

$mailstatus = l_mail('', '', $to, '', $frm, '', $sub, $mail_body);

if ($mailstatus == 'ok') {
    echo '<center><font color=red style="font-size:14px">Message has been sent Succesfully.....!</font></center><br>';
} else {
    echo $mailstatus;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$to = "pbvamsi@gmail.com";
 $subject = "Hey keep belief in me!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?\n\n be good do good";
 $header="god@heaven.com";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $header)) {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
  }
```

I hope this works

Answer (score 0):

use the below code when you create object of the phpmailer class

```
$mail = new phpmailer();
$mail->IsHTML(true);
```

thanks